# Forbidden on Form Submit with Specific English Characters

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, .htaccess

I have subdirectory in Wordpress installation. I created a form with textarea and when I submit that form it submit successfully. But when I enter some other English characters it goes to Forbidden. I don't know what's happing :(

Here i putted a test form in same directory:
http://www.irj.science/vuadmin/test.php

I put following lines and get results like:

**I put:** In image processing, the maximum entropy principle is generally recognized as having
**Result:** Successfully Submitted

**I put:** In image processing, the maximum entropy principle is generally recognized as having a
**Result:** Forbidden Page

**I put:** In image processing, the maximum entropy principle is generally recognized as havint a
**Result:** Successfully Submitted

Please check the issue when is happening here.

I did the following:
Excluded this form folder from wordpress htaccess - Still no success

changed Textarea name - Still no Success

Off Security via htaccess - Still no Success

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/vuadmin/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/vuadmin/(.*)$ [OR]` ... should be followed by another `RewriteCond` not a rule... I'd have expected that to `HTTP 500` though

Comment: I removed [OR] then it does not go to Forbidden page, it goes to wordpress 404 page. Means does not exclude /vuadmin/ folder from wordpress htaccess

Comment: Post the source of your PHP page?

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['done'])){
 echo "Submitted: ".$_POST['aabstract'];
}`